# Why insert request got an error response via Youtube API?

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I request an insert api via Youtube API for starting live streaming and I got an error such as below image.

I knew that it's available live streaming with other tools.(refer to https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2853834)

I have submitted their review request for using a scopes, and our project was accepted by them.

Same request with other client ID is working, but my clientId not working.

Can you explain why it happens?

Comment: Please dont add screen shots of code and error messages.   Just add the text properly formated.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to live stream on mobile, your channel will need to have at least 1,000 subscribers.

[link](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2853834?hl=en)